# Entities from Google Vision API have no infromation in Knowledge Graph API

Tags: google-api, google-vision, google-knowledge-graph

I use the Google Vision API to detect themes in images, and I then use the Knowledge Graph API to retrieve information about those themes (such as a description, a thumbnail, and a Wikpedia link, for instance). However, I sometimes find that entities returned by the Vision API have no information whatsoever in the Knowledge Graph.

Here is an example.

Using [Google Vision API Demo](https://cloud.google.com/vision), analyze [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep0z7.jpg).

In the returned JSON, you can see "Atmospheric Phenomenon" as a detected label, with its Knowledge Graph identifier.

```
{
  "labelAnnotations": [
    {
      "description": "Atmospheric phenomenon",
      "mid": "/m/07pw27b",
      "score": 0.874821,
      "topicality": 0.874821
    },
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
}
```

You can verify that the entity exists, by searching it directly on Google via the following URL.

http://g.co/kg/m/07pw27b

[image]

However, when using the [Knowledge Graph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22ids%22%3A%5B%22%2Fm%2F02h7lkt%22%5D%7D) to fetch information about that entity, the response is empty.

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
    "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "kg": "http://g.co/kg",
    "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
    "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": []
}
```

---

**How come that certain entities returned by the Vision API have no information in the Knowledge Graph?**

Comment: http://g.co/kg/m/07pw27b searches for  knowledge graph search api, is that correct?

Comment: It is the URI of the Knowledge Graph concept for "Atmospheric Phenomenon". Opening it in your browser will run a pseudo Google Search, which returns nothing, as I have described in the question. If you want to try it on a working URI, you can use [g.co/kg/m/0dl567](http://g.co/kg/m/0dl567).